# using If statment included in axpx page generates compile error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, compiler-errors

i have a  default.aspx

and  a  sidebar.aspx

i included the sidebar in my default by :

```
<!--#include file="../sidebar.aspx"-->
```

it included successfully  without any error
i used this code in my sidbar file :

```
<% if (True) { %>
    <div class="left-box">
        ....
    </div>
<% } %>
```

it works fine when i refresh the page @ development server
but  vs 2010 shows  compile error  :

> Error  25  End of statement expected.  C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite2\sidebar.aspx   6
>
> Error  24  'If' must end with a matching 'End If'. C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite2\sidebar.aspx   6
>
> Error  26  Syntax error.   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite2\sidebar.aspx   22

UPDATEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE ! ->
at top of my default.aspx is ->
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
and then i included my sidebar.aspx .... i dont know why sidebar run as VB ... i didnt use any page language at top of this file ... and it should use the default.aspx language

Comment: If it's expecting an end if, then it's trying to parse Visual Basic.  I don't use .NET servers, but I'd think there's some way to change it to use C# instead.

Answer (score 1):

Check the 'language' attribute in your <%@ Page %> directive. Make sure it is set to "c#" (the error message makes it sound like the page is using vb)

Comment: at top of my default.aspx  is ->        <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>                                                                           and then i included my sidebar.aspx ....  i dont know why sidebar run as VB ...  i didnt use any page language at top of this file ...   and it should use the default.aspx language

Comment: what is the language setting in your sidebar.aspx file?

Answer (score 0):

change `True` to `true`. It's trying to compile as VB.NET

Comment: at top of my default.aspx  is ->        <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>                                                                           and then i included my sidebar.aspx ....  i dont know why sidebar run as VB ...  i didnt use any page language at top of this file ...   and it should use the default.aspx language

Comment: Each `aspx` page is compiled separately. My guess is that the top of sidebar.aspx you don't have any language declaration so .NET tries to guess the language based on the first bit of script (`if (True)...`). Verify that you have a line in your web.config like `<compilation defaultLanguage="C#">`

Answer (score 0):

Other than changing the "True", to "true", it works fine for me...are you sure the page is expecting C# code, and not VB code?

Comment: at top of my default.aspx  is ->        <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>                                                                           and then i included my sidebar.aspx ....  i dont know why sidebar run as VB ...  i didnt use any page language at top of this file ...   and it should use the default.aspx language

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
if ( 1 == 1) {
```

Comment: at top of my default.aspx  is ->        <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>                                                                           and then i included my sidebar.aspx ....  i dont know why sidebar run as VB ...  i didnt use any page language at top of this file ...   and it should use the default.aspx language